# Flot: Equi-Distant Gridlines for a Logarithmic Scaled Axis?

Tags: flot

I have a graph/plot area which looks like following:

[image]

As you can see that the grid lines are not equi-distant.

Following is the code of plotting ticks and grid lines. Since the scale is logarithmic, I figured-out that following shall be a convenient method of transformation.

```
function setUpflot(){
            // setup plot
             myTestArray = getRandomData();

             var options = {
                // series  : { shadowSize: 0, splines: {show:true,lineWidth:1}},
                 series  : { },
                 xaxis   : { tickLength:0,  show: false },
                 yaxis   :{

            //position: "left",
            ticks: [[55,""],[68.75,""],[82.5,""],[96.25,""],[110,"110"],

                   [136.25,""],[165,""],[192.5,""],[220,"220"],[275,""],[330,""],

                   [385,""],[440,"440"],[550,""],[660,""],[770,""],[880,""]],


            transform:function(v){return Math.log(v*1.44);}, 
            tickColor:"rgba(148,129,151,0.5)",
            min: minGraphY, max:maxGraphY,show: true
                            },


        y2axis   :{
                            //position: "right",


                            ticks: [[55,""],[68.75,""],[82.5,""],[96.25,""],[110,"A2"],

                            [136.25,""],[165,""],[192.5,""],[220,"A3"],[275,""],[330,""],

                            [385,""],[440,"A4"],[550,""],[660,""],[770,""],[880,""]],

             alignTicksWithAxis: true,


            transform:function(v){return Math.log(v*1.44);}, 


            tickColor:"rgba(148,129,151,0.5)",


            min: minGraphY,


            max:maxGraphY,


            show: true,


            tickLength: 0
        },

                grid    : { 
                borderWidth:0,          
                backgroundColor: 
                                       {
                    colors: ["#5d0d3f","#5d0d3f","#5d0d3f",

                              "#6e0326","#724922","#724922",

                              "#2a5631","#724922","#724922","#6e0326",

                              "#5d0d3f","#5d0d3f","#5d0d3f"]

             }
            }
          };
```

I need the grid lines to be equi-distant. How would I achieve that?

Thnx.

Comment: What version of Flot are you using?

Comment: @DNS its not the latest its before 0.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, achieved it.

I had a logarithmic scale so I followed the following

**Step 1**

*Range*: 55-880

*Initial Steps*: 55,110,220,440,880

**Step 2**

Calculate log of Initial Steps

**Step 3**

Calculate the differences between the log values -e.g- value_of_log(110) - value_of_log(55)

**Step 4**

Using Brute Force/Hit'n'Trial, insert values between the Initial Steps so that the differences between the log values remain same.

**PS:** I have attached the screenshots as sample.

**Sample Table**
[image: Sample Table]

**Output**

[image: Output]

Hope This Helps !

Comment: The intermediate values / new inserted ticks are square root of 2 times the lower initial tick.